# If function on two differently formatted date/datetime variable in SQL/SAS

Tags: sql, datetime, if-statement, sas, format

I have a dataset with two date columns (Conversion Date, click_date) that are formatted differently (Conversion Date: ymdhms., click_date: date9.)

What I want to do is create an If/Case When statement in my script that compares the two dates, and if the dates are the same I want it to add 1 day to the Conversion Date. Here is a sample:

[image: Sample of Data]

So in this case we can see that 10/28/2022 matches with click_date in the 2nd row, this should show as "10/29/2022 02:03:49" in the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way using the intnx function. Here is the line of code I used:

```
if click_date = datepart("Conversion Date"n) then "conversion date"n=intnx('dtday', "conversion date"n, 1, 'same');
else "Conversion Date"n = "Conversion Date"n;
```